# How can I autoresize my graph with the width/length of my browser window?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, plotly

I want to auto resize my plotly graph when the browser window size changes.
Something like `{responsive: true}` or `style="width:100%;`.
My code Python `(Flask)` goes like this:

```js
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def notdash():
   df = pd.DataFrame({
      'Fruit': ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Bananas', 'Apples', 'Oranges', Bananas'],
      'Amount': [4, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5],
      'City': ['SF', 'SF', 'SF', 'Montreal', 'Montreal', 'Montreal']
   })
   fig = px.bar(df, x='Fruit', y='Amount', color='City', barmode='group')
   graphJSON = json.dumps(fig, cls=plotly.utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
   
   return render_template('notdash.html', graphJSON=graphJSON)
```

And for the `JS`:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <body>
  <h1>Plotly chart</h1>
  <div id='chart' class='chart'”></div>
</body>

<script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var graphs = {{graphJSON | safe}};
  Plotly.plot('chart',graphs,{});
</script>
</html>
```